# ADX/Kusto - alternative to pivot or back_unpack when the use of evaluate is restricted

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Good day,

I have a table that contains 3 columns, Timestamp, String, Value.
I would like to pivot the table so that the values in the column "String" become the Name of the columns. I am able to achieve this both with pivot and bag_unpack.

The system where I need to integrate such a query has restricted the use of the evaluate operator to avoid problems when trying to pivot dynamic columns.

Can you think of a solution to achieve the same without using evaluate?
This would be the example with pivot:

```
let table = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, String: string, Value:int)[
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column A", 10,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column B" , 11,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column C", 12,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column A", 20,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column B" , 21,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column C", 22
] ;
table
| evaluate pivot(String, take_any(Value), Timestamp)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward aggregation with hard-coded values.

```
let table = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, String: string, Value:int)[
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column A", 10,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column B" , 11,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column C", 12,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column A", 20,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column B" , 21,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column C", 22
] ;
table
| summarize ["Column A"] = take_anyif(Value, String == "Column A")
           ,["Column B"] = take_anyif(Value, String == "Column B")
           ,["Column C"] = take_anyif(Value, String == "Column C")
            by Timestamp
```

| Timestamp | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-09T06:54:55.28Z | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 2023-02-09T06:55:55.28Z | 20 | 21 | 22 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WSXWvCMBSG7wP5Dy%209aiGOeGZly%20iF9ids7KaIRIwjrOmGTS8Uf7w1oBWpRXOTD/K8eTgnpfHwelUaZFhrr8M6/rLO1F67f9WeGd/uBD791lY/CnWYBb512RhlK58UnJ2vxSTpdSRpJN8hpyqdqDR9oTeZCET5X9m4CrNIYCzFU8w8QguNn4Py00M0wKT9cjQk18MEORqS64FOckScLfDBWSg6ZwfUjXN6a/cGRWe0aFvj9a9Z6mpnN3Go%207kdyLIr94QzdEMUneGjGfO7GfnDGflNBlY7XD7UEdFos1lwAgAA)

P.S.

You (and/or who is in charge on the system) should be aware that [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin#pivot-with-a-query-defined-output-schema) has a variation that supports a pre-defined output schema.

```
let table = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, String: string, Value:int)[
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column A", 10,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column B" , 11,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column C", 12,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column A", 20,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column B" , 21,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column C", 22
] ;
table
| evaluate pivot(String, take_any(Value), Timestamp) : (Timestamp:datetime, ["Column A"]:string, ["Column B"]:string, ["Column C"]:string)
```

| Timestamp | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-09T06:54:55.28Z | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 2023-02-09T06:55:55.28Z | 20 | 21 | 22 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WRzQrCMBCE74W%20w9JTClHS1YpGPGgfoeKliEQMUmxjsduC4MMbgz%20XUPCUZMi3mcxUmoDUsdKwgpMi5fZsW9a6JVU30mqa7IlDTrfSnCW0buWwU1WnZWkoLsLgc42hwMlI4EgsQMxkOpVpOsa5iDlE2bXqagPriEMi%20F/MJgILJf9B2eshHGBSvzkcMudhnDkcMueBXuYQw2APyzBwoYfBA3RvQ7VDoCn7K7H8HTWpiz4oc2cuczvl208MErxtFb8f7eWnsuJn2SNmXzF%20AnZHCBAWAgAA)

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the answer. What if the String column is dynamic? I am unable to define the column name in advance. I would require exactly what the pivot plugin does.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the issue with dynamic (the code works As Is, even with `String: dynamic`). Anyways, if your output schema is unknown in advance, you need a plugin (the unknown output schema is exactly why pivot & bag_unpack are considered plugins and not stand-alone operators).

Comment: Thank you David, I meant exactly that the schema is unknown. Then there is no workaround if not with evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicit schema definition, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin#pivot-with-a-query-defined-output-schema)

```
let table = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, String: string, Value:int)[
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column A", 10,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column B" , 11,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:54:55.280), "Column C", 12,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column A", 20,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column B" , 21,
datetime(2023-02-09 06:55:55.280), "Column C", 22
] ;
table
| evaluate pivot(String, take_any(Value), Timestamp): (Timestamp:datetime, ['Column A']: int, ['Column B']: int, ['Column C']: int)
```